# Render .NET HyperLink as text only

Tags: asp.net, .net

is there anything we can do in the code behind to render this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnk" NavigateUrl="~/test.aspx" runat="server">link text</asp:HyperLink>
```

as text only:

```
link text
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do want to render an hyperlink as a text ? Maybe explaining your goal will help us to understand.

Comment: Do you want to keep the "link" functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a user control that has two controls, a `HyperLink` and a `Label` (or a `LiteralControl`) and switch the visibility between those two.

Add public properties to the user control for all properties that you require, e.g. `NavigateUrl`, `Text`, etc.

Comment: how do you add html to it? I tried: Label.Text = "<div>XXX</div>"; but it renders it as text rather than a tag: &lt;div&gt;XXX&lt;/div&gt;

Comment: You can use `LiteralControl` to render your text as HTML

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set the `NavigateUrl` to `null`, but you will retain the `<a>` tags in the markup. So, it will be matter of using CSS to style it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to exchange the Hyperlink control against a LiteralControl, if you don't want a link, then don't use a link.